# KineticJS and HTML5 - Drag dont work

Tags: html, drag-and-drop, kineticjs, shapes

I have a problem with KineticJS - there is no drag on my shape.

What is wrong with my code? - Iam really stuck and need somebody KineticJS-shark.

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

<script src="kinetic-v4.0.4.min.js"></script>
<script>
window.onload = function() {
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
container: "container",
width: 1024,
height: 768
});
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var spaceShip = new Kinetic.Shape({

drawFunc: function (context) {

context.beginPath();
context.moveTo(99.3, 161.4);
context.bezierCurveTo(99.3, 143.2, 92.5, 128.4, 84.2, 128.4);
context.bezierCurveTo(83.6, 128.4, 83.1, 128.4, 82.6, 128.6);
context.bezierCurveTo(76.5, 84.1, 53.0, 8.0, 53.0, 8.0);
context.bezierCurveTo(53.0, 8.0, 29.6, 84.0, 23.5, 128.5);
context.bezierCurveTo(23.0, 128.4, 22.6, 128.4, 22.2, 128.4);
context.bezierCurveTo(13.8, 128.4, 7.0, 143.2, 7.0, 161.4);
context.bezierCurveTo(7.0, 179.6, 22.2, 228.9, 22.2, 228.9);
context.bezierCurveTo(22.2, 228.9, 27.2, 212.4, 31.5, 194.9);
context.bezierCurveTo(37.1, 206.7, 44.7, 213.9, 53.0, 213.9);
context.bezierCurveTo(61.5, 213.9, 69.1, 206.5, 74.7, 194.6);
context.bezierCurveTo(79.0, 212.2, 84.2, 228.9, 84.2, 228.9);
context.bezierCurveTo(84.2, 228.9, 99.3, 179.6, 99.3, 161.4);
context.closePath();
context.fillStyle = "rgb(203, 203, 203)";
context.fill();


context.bezierCurveTo(37.9, 97.3, 42.4, 92.8, 48.0, 92.8);
context.bezierCurveTo(53.7, 92.8, 58.2, 97.3, 58.2, 102.9);
context.closePath();
context.fillStyle = "rgb(255, 255, 255)";
context.fill();


},


});


// add the shape to the layer
layer.add(spaceShip);

// add the layer to the stage
stage.add(layer);

spaceShip.setDraggable(true);

spaceShip.on('dragstart', function() {
    console.log("Drag start");      
});

spaceShip.on('dragend', function() {
    console.log("Drag end");        
});




};
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

(What more do you want me to write StackOverflow???)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this below code

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>

    <script src="http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/libraries/kinetic-v4.0.3.js"></script>

    <script>
        window.onload = function() {
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({
                container: "container",
                width: 1024,
                height: 768
            });
            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();

            var spaceShip = new Kinetic.Shape({
                drawFunc: function (context) {
                    context.beginPath();
                    context.moveTo(99.3, 161.4);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(99.3, 143.2, 92.5, 128.4, 84.2, 128.4);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(83.6, 128.4, 83.1, 128.4, 82.6, 128.6);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(76.5, 84.1, 53.0, 8.0, 53.0, 8.0);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(53.0, 8.0, 29.6, 84.0, 23.5, 128.5);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(23.0, 128.4, 22.6, 128.4, 22.2, 128.4);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(13.8, 128.4, 7.0, 143.2, 7.0, 161.4);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(7.0, 179.6, 22.2, 228.9, 22.2, 228.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(22.2, 228.9, 27.2, 212.4, 31.5, 194.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(37.1, 206.7, 44.7, 213.9, 53.0, 213.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(61.5, 213.9, 69.1, 206.5, 74.7, 194.6);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(79.0, 212.2, 84.2, 228.9, 84.2, 228.9);
                    context.bezierCurveTo(84.2, 228.9, 99.3, 179.6, 99.3, 161.4);
                    context.closePath();
                    this.fill(context);
                    this.stroke(context);
                },
                draggable:true,
                fill: "#00D2FF",
                stroke: "black",
                strokeWidth: 1
            });

            // add the shape to the layer
            layer.add(spaceShip);

            // add the layer to the stage
            stage.add(layer);

            spaceShip.on('dragstart', function() {
                console.log("Drag start");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Drag start";
            });

            spaceShip.on('dragend', function() {
                console.log("Drag end");
                document.getElementById("display").innerHTML = "Drag end";
            });

        };
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<div id="container"></div>
<div id="display"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

When using custom shapes, you need to be sure to use the KineticJS fill() and stroke() methods or else you won't be able to bind events to the shape.  Here's an example:

http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-kineticjs-shape-tutorial/

This is necessary because the KienticJS fill() and stroke() methods are also used to draw onto the invisible buffer layer used for high performance event detection